# Text-only image tabs in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

Is there a way to make image tabs in GIMP ver 2.10.12 only contain text (e.g. image file name, etc.)?

I couldn`t find anything on the topic in GIMP preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and No:

This is not possible with any released or unreleased version of GIMP yet, but as the source code for GIMP is available, anyone with the skills, the time and the motivation can implement this and contribute a patch or a merge request.

Tracking the following issue report is a good way of finding out when this will be available, the report would change to Closed and have a target milestone assigned then: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/939